# UDP stream with little packets

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, client-server, packet

I have a little network with a client and a server, and I'm testing the FrameRate, changing the dimension of the packet. Particulary, I have an image, changing threshold, I extract keypoints and descriptors and then I send a fixed number of packets (with different dimension with different threshold). Problems happen when udp packets are under MTU dimension, reception rate decrease and frame rate tend to be constant. I verify with wireshark that my reception times are correct, so isn't a server code problem.

this is the graph with the same image sends 30 times for threshold with a 10 step from 40 to 170.

[i can't post the image so this is the link](http://postimg.org/image/qvxakutnj/)

Thanks for the responces

Answer (score 2):

I think that none will find this answer really interesting, but we arrived to the conclusion that the problem is in the wifi dongle's drivers.

The transmission window does not go under a determined time's threshold. So, under a determined amount of data while time remains constant, it decreases.